# Scheduling a task with AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to create a task scheduler. For now I just want to have a Toast message pop up once a scheduled broadcast received. So I have this BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int group_id = intent.getIntExtra("SELECTED_GROUP", 0);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast received. Selected group ID: "+group_id, 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my AndroidManifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="com.ikmedia.smscheduler.receivers.AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.mysite.myapp.sendSchedule"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in my activity this is what I have when the user hits the Save button:

```
Calendar calendar_schedule_time = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar_schedule_time.set(selected_year, selected_month, selected_day, selected_hour, selected_minute);
Intent intent_scheduler = new Intent();
intent_scheduler.setAction("com.mysite.myapp.sendSchedule");
intent_scheduler.putExtra("SELECTED_GROUP", selected_group_id);
PendingIntent pi_schedule_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Constants.Request_Codes.REQUEST_CODE_SEND_SCHEDULE, intent_scheduler, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_schedule_time.getTimeInMillis(), pi_schedule_intent);
```

However when I hit the Save button - I don't get a scheduled alarm, but an immediate response from the BroadcastReceiver. I have the Toast message pops up, with the Extra text, but it happens immediately and I don't have the schedule.

Why is that? How do I fix it?

Comment: Hi can you please tell me what are you passing when setting calendar? I mean just let me know the parameters you're passing.

Comment: I pass values retrieved from DatePicker and TimePicker.

Comment: Well I tried your code, and seems to be working fine. I tried with `alarm_manager.set` not `setInexactRepeating` and that's working as it has to be. You may have look at my snippet from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43315063/Alarm_app.zip

Import and run on device and let me know if this is working

Comment: @GiGa Yes, everything worked this time! My problem was with the TimePicker, as it was set to 24 hours format, but I was picking hour as a 12 hour format. Could you please post your reply as an answer so I could accept it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_schedule_time.getTimeInMillis(), pi_schedule_intent);
```

replace the above statement with :-

```
alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + calendar_schedule_time.getTimeInMillis(), pi_schedule_intent);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `The method getTimeInMillis() is undefined for the type System`

Comment: Nope, that still didn't work. However I fount out that using `alarm_manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_schedule_time.getTimeInMillis(), 30000, pi_schedule_intent)` instead of `set()` works just fine. The problem is what happens if I want it to be a 1 time only task, non-repeating?